# live USB linux on macbook pro mid 2012

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, usb, macintosh

I need to create a live USB with a Linux os on it. I have a MacBook Pro mid 2012.

I tried to follow various instructions for both Fedora and Ubuntu. However in the end I was not able to install neither. 
In particular with Fedora, I get this when I boot it (i get the same screen on both my Mac and an Acer Aspire One):

[image]

so my questions are:

1. what is the problem?
2. Is it possible to install a version that is working? if yes, which one?
3. the eventual live USB would be bootable on both a mac and a windows?
4. what should I do to get this live USB working correctly?

EDIT

@mattdm I followed fedora's instructions. I will try now with another USB.

@schaiba I did not verify the image downloaded, and I do not know how to do that. Which kind of files do I need and in which format?; and what should I do in the terminal to verify the image? I cannot understand very well the instructions I found on the website.

Comment: You say that you followed "various instructions". There's a lot of information on the internet, and not surprisingly, some of it is wrong. For Fedora, did you use the official Fedora Media Writer tool?

Comment: Do you have a _different_ USB drive you can try?

Comment: There are pretty straightforward instructions on Fedora's download page : https://getfedora.org/verify

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be something amiss with the media, either the image or the stick itself. Before installing and writing to the USB stick, check the image's checksum and make sure it's OK.